# Let $X$ be a discrete random variable and let $Y = 0.5 X + 3$. Given PMF of $X$, find PMF of $Y, E [Y ]$ and $Var[Y]$.

Tags: discrete-mathematics, random-variables, variance, density-function, means

**Question :** Let $X$ be a discrete random variable and let $Y = 0.5 X + 3$

1. Assume that the PMF of $X$ is given by, where $k$ is some suitable constant. Determine the value of $k$.

> $\frac{1}{40}$

2. Find $E[X]$ and $Var[X]$.

> $E[X]=0, Var[X]=0$

3. Given that $X$ has the PMF found above, find the PMF of $Y$ .
4. Without explicit calculation from the PMF of $Y$, find $E [Y ]$ and $Var[Y]$.

I have found answer for 1. and 2. Please help me in remaining parts.

Comment: The image description failed, so I do not know the distribution of $X$. For the mean, variance of $Y$, use the fact that $E(aX+b)=aE(X)+b$ and $\text{Var}(aX+b)=a^2\text{Var}(X)$.  By the way, it is highly unlikely that $\text{Var}(X)=0$.